# How can I patch a nested form Array?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-forms, angular11

I have two reactive forms. one form for adding a new 'agreement' and adding 'contacts' to it and the other form shows all the added agreements and contacts and has inline editing (adding/deleting contacts).
I can add agreements and contacts in my first form but I have to patch it to the second form upon submission.
My first form looks something like this:

```
formInitializer() {
this.agrmntsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  sales_price: new FormControl(''),
  closing_cost_support: new FormControl(''),
  financing: new FormControl(''),
  contract_date: new FormControl(''),
  inspection_period: new FormControl(''),
  closing_date: new FormControl(''),
  contacts: this.formBuilder.array([]),
})}
```

the second form looks something like this :

```
mainFormInitializer() {
this.mainForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  agreements: this.formBuilder.array([]),
});}
```

Here's a stackblitz with all the code up to this point:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-sfgv2i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I need to patch all the data coming from the agrmntsForm into the mainForm every time the user adds a new agreement.
Currently I can only patch the agreements array but can't seem to figure out how to patch the contacts array.

Comment: Hi Aizaz, 
There is a dirty simple solution to workaround.
1-> Set the aggrements as FormControl
2-> Set the Value instead of Patch the Value
     mainFormInitializer() {
          agreements: new FormControl(),
      }
    patchControls(data2) {
          this.mainForm.controls['agreements'].setValue(obj);
      }

This is your working stack overflow https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-yglpav?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hey. forgive me If I am doing something wrong but your solution doesn't seem to patch the data in my form (in your stackblitz code)